# How to change a ListBox's Vertical Scrollbar's Repeat Button Size in WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, scrollbar

I have a ListBox control with a vertical scrollbar. I would like to increase the Repeat Buttons' Height to something bigger because our UI is touch-compatible.

Is there a simple way to do it ?

Thank you and best regards,

Romanin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to modify the ControlTemplate for a vertical scrollbar and change it to what you want: [ScrollBar ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It's not so easy to just change the button sizes, because they are hardcoded in the default template. But you can scale the whole ScrollBar control by a factor. Just put this Style to your Window or Control resources.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
      <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0"
                               ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
           </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: This is the one that really worked for me