# How to increase vertical scrollbar arrows in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

HERE IS PHOTO OF MY VERTICAL SCROLLBAR:
[image]
I've been trying to increase size of this arrows but unfortunately I could not make it work,
I changed background colour of those arrows, but unfortunately I could not find how to edit their size..

Could anyone help me about this please, I would appreciate this so much!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a ListBox's Vertical Scrollbar's Repeat Button Size in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832148/how-to-change-a-listboxs-vertical-scrollbars-repeat-button-size-in-wpf)

Comment: @Fang No it's not duplicate, I don't want to change size of repeat button,
I want to change gylph (arrow) inside of a repeat button..

Comment: This is perfectly valid question. It is not obvious how to increase the size of the glyph and the desired behavior was described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ScrollBar template on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278076(v=vs.95).aspx), you need to change the `VerticalIncrementTemplate` and `VerticalDecrementTemplate`, from there you will find the style for the Arrows, i.e.:

```
 <Path Stretch="Uniform" Height="4" Width="8" Data="F1 M 541.537,173.589L 531.107,173.589L 536.322,167.49L 541.537,173.589 Z ">
```

So you could increase the `Height` and `Width` to make the arrow bigger.

Comment: so I should copy/paste   <!-- Vertical Inc/Dec Templates --> part  to my project and edit that template?